# how to fetch api data asynchronously with query from input field?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, fetch-api

I am practicing creating a weather app and I want to fetch data using async await. But before that, I need to read the city name that user provides in search bar. In my current code, the async function tries to fetch data without the city being set in the query.
How can I handle this with best practices, such that this weather api call is made only after citname is retrieved?
Please find my code below:

```
'use strict';

(function() {
    const inputEl = document.querySelector(".search-placholder");
    let cityName = '';

    const debounce = (func, wait, immediate) => {
        var timeout;
        return function() {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var later = function() {
                timeout = null;
                if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
            };
            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
            if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
        };
    };

    const handleSearchText= debounce(function(e) {
        cityName = e.target.value;
        console.log(cityName);
        inputEl.placeholder = cityName;
    }, 250);

    inputEl.addEventListener("keyup", handleSearchText);

    // make request to openweatherapi & make api call
    async function getWeatherdata(event) {
        const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=2489ed561dc99d173a2f394574bc107e`;
        const response = await fetch(url);
        console.log(url)
        return response.json();
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    inputEl.addEventListener('submit', () => getWeatherdata());

})();
```

```js
'use strict';

(function() {
 const inputEl = document.querySelector(".search-placholder");
 // Get the form element.
 const formEl = document.querySelector('form.weatherdata-form');
 let cityName = '';

 const debounce = (func, wait, immediate) => {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
   var context = this, args = arguments;
   var later = function() {
    timeout = null;
    if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
   };
   var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
   clearTimeout(timeout);
   timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
   if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
 };

 const handleSearchText = debounce((e) => {
  cityName = e.target.value;
  inputEl.placeholder = cityName;
 }, 250);

 inputEl.addEventListener("keyup", handleSearchText);

 // make request to openweatherapi & make api call
 async function getWeatherdata(event) {
  const form = event.target.form;
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  let cityName = formData.get('city-name');
  console.log(cityName)
  const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=2489ed561dc99d173a2f394574bc107e`;
  const response = await fetch(url, {
   method: 'POST',
   body: formData
  });
  event.preventDefault();
  return response.json();
 }

 const weatherDetails = formEl.addEventListener('submit', getWeatherdata);
 console.log(weatherDetails)

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>My cool weather app</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
 <main>
  <div class="search-container">
   <div class="search-bar">
    <form class="weatherdata-form">
     <i class="fa fa-search fa-3x" id="icon"></i>
     <input type="text" class="search-placholder" placeholder="Type city to find weather..." name="city-name"/>
     <!-- <button type="submit">Submit</button> -->
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </main>
 <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your `submit` event listener to the `form` element instead of the button directly. This will give you the posibility to extract all the values of form elements from your form with the [`FormData API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData).

Make sure that your `input` fields have the `name` attribute as we will use this to get the values you need.

```
<form class="weatherdata-form">
  <input class="search-placholder" type="text" name="city-name"/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
// Get the form element.
const formEl = document.querySelector('form.weatherdata-form');
```

Modify your `getWeatherdata` function to extract the `target` property of the current Event. This will give us information which form this is that has been submitted. This opens up the possibility to make this function applicable to other forms.

Create an instance of `FormData` with the `form` as argument to create an extraction of your inputs with their names and values. With the [`FormData.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get) method you can pick a single value from the form by giving its name. Inject that value in to your URL string and you're done here.

### Edit

The `form` constant came up undefined and should have been `event.target`; No form was found and so no values were found. I've also added a check that if `cityName` is an empty string it will stop the function and not call the `fetch`. Remove the `if` statement if you want to call `fetch` without conditions.

```
async function getWeatherdata(event) {
  const form = event.target;
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  const cityName = formData.get('city-name');
  if (cityName === '') return;
  event.preventDefault();
  const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=2489ed561dc99d173a2f394574bc107e`;
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const json = await response.json();
  console.log(json);
}
```

Add the event listener to the form element and set the listener callback directly to the `getWeatherdata` function. Now the form will submit the event and open up all the values of the form to use.

```
formEl.addEventListener('submit', getWeatherdata);
```

Hope this helps you out, friend. If this didn't solve your question or you have more questions, please let me know.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks so much for an elaborate explanation! I have 2 questions now: 1. Where does cityName come from here -> const cityName = formData.get('cityName'); 2. Does my handleSearchText function remain unchanged?

Comment: The `<input class="search-placholder">` should have a `name` attribute. In this I thought it would be suitable to assume the name of that input is `cityName`. I'll add it to the answer. And Yes, `handleSearchText` does not interfere with `getWeatherdata` and does not have to be changed.

Comment: I still get null for cityName.

Comment: Does your `input` have the same `name` attribute value as the name argument in `formData.get(name);`? If it does not have the result will be null. Otherwise could you create a snippet to work with the rest of your code?

Comment: I just edited my question to include snippet. Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out. Added explanation to my answer at the **Edit** line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206219/discussion-between-theusual-and-emiel-zuurbier).